# How Does Allocated Memory Get Freed In C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, sfml

Let's say I have a header file, armorshop.h, containing a class definition, along with a corresponding .cpp for this header file.

My question is:

1. How does allocated memory get freed in c++?
2. Will allocatedmemory1, allocatedmemory2, allocatedmemory3, or allocatedmemory4 ever be freed on its own in each of these scenarios?
3. Will these aformentioned allocatedmemories be redefined and cause an error in each of these scenarios?
4. Do variables and classes, etc defined *inside* of a class definition get freed when they are not being used, and redefined when they are used again? Or do they get defined once and use up resources while not being used?

Thanks

```
//scenario 1
//armorshop.h
#ifndef __SFML__armorshop__
#define __SFML__armorshop__


class armorshop : public entity
{
public:

};

int allocatedmemory1;
sf::FloatRect allocatedmemory2;
class armorshop allocatedmemory3;
std::vector<armorshop> allocatedmemory4;

#endif
```

(question 3 clarification in relation to scenario 1:) If I `#include "armorshop.h"` multiple times will this cause an error

```
//scenario 2
//armorshop.cpp
int allocatedmemory1;
sf::FloatRect allocatedmemory2;
class armorshop allocatedmemory3;
std::vector<armorshop> allocatedmemory4;
```

Comment: (1) `How does allocated memory get freed in c++?` Depends on how it got allocated in the first place. (2) Global variables are destroyed when the program terminates. (3) I'm not sure what you mean by "redefined". Your scenario 1 does invite ODR violation and linker errors, if that's what you are asking - it's unwise to define variables in a header file (it's OK to declare them there with an `extern` keyword, and define in exactly one source file).

Comment: (4) Classes are not objects and don't occupy memory. Non-static variables declared within a class are member variables - they are only created as part of the class' instance. Each instance has its own copy of them.

Comment: What is the proper way to give multiple files access to allocatedmemory2?

Comment: In a header file, write `extern sf::FloatRect allocatedmemory2;` In exactly one source file, write `sf::FloatRect allocatedmemory2;`. Include the header as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How does allocated memory get freed in c++?

*How* memory is freed, depends on the implementation, and how the memory was allocated in the first place.

> 2. Will allocatedmemory1, allocatedmemory2, allocatedmemory3, or allocatedmemory4 ever be freed on its own in each of these scenarios?

All of those variables have static storage duration. Objects with static storage duration are deallocated after `main` has returned.

Whether global variables were defined in a header file that is included in a source file (scenario 1), or the globals were defined in a source file directly (scenario 2), makes no difference to when the variables are "freed".

> 4. Do variables and ... get freed when they are not being used

Nothing is "freed" based on whether they are used or not.

> Do ... classes ... get freed

Classes are not "freed".

> If I #include "armorshop.h" multiple times will this cause an error

`armorshop.h` defines global variables. Including the header in multiple source files will cause each source file to define those same variables. That violates the one definition rule. You should hardly ever define global variables in a header.

PS. `__SFML__armorshop__` is a reserved identifier, because it contains two consecutive underscores. Defining it in your code makes your program ill-formed.

Comment: thanks this answers all my questions simply and thoroughly

Comment: *"`__SFML__armorshop__` is a reserved identifier, because it [...] begins with an underscore."* - That alone doesn't make it a reserved symbol. Symbols in C++ are reserved if they contain two consecutive underscores, begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter, or begin with an underscore at global scope.

Comment: @user2079303 Preprocessor has no concept of scope (global or otherwise), so the question is meaningless.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik & IInspectable OK then. Thanks for clarifying. I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-part question.

The first part, is that if the globally-scoped objects get declared in a header file in this fashion, and this header file gets included from multiple translation units, this is undefined behavior, and will typically result in duplicate symbol declaration errors during the link phase. A recently-adopted addition to the forthcoming `C++17` allows globally-scoped objects to be declared as `inline`, permitting them to be declared in multiple translation units, as defined behavior.

For the second part, the globally-scoped objects get declared in a single translation unit, the globally-scoped objects get constructed at some point before `main()` is invoked, and they get destroyed, or deallocated, at some point after `main()` returns. The relative order in which statically-scoped objects in different translation units get constructed or destroyed is not specified. Only the relative order in which statically-scoped objects in the same translation unit get constructed, or destroyed, is specified.

Comment: Thanks for the hasty answer, it answers half of my question. I didn't involve this second part in the question but how could I give different header files and .cpp files access to `sf::FloatRect allocatedmemory2;` without `#include`ing them in the fashion of scenario 1?, or defining multiple floatRects in each .cpp file that needs it like in scenario 2?